# Sum different cell that link to checkbox (if true, then sum the value)

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I got a problem to sum the amount in the green box. The thing is, whenever the checkbox ticked (true) then the cell contain an amount will turn to green. I want to make the sum formula only for the green boxes for total revenue from January to December (horizontal data).

[Sum the green box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFFzS.png)

Comment: Are on google-sheet or excel? Use `SUMIFS()` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you help me with the sumifs() formula base on the picture i have attached.